# Compute area under density estimation curve, i.e., probability

Tags: r, probability, kernel-density, probability-density, density-plot

I have a density estimate (using `density` function) for my data `learningTime` (see figure below), and I need to find probability `Pr(learningTime > c)`, i.e., the the area under density curve from a given number `c` (the red vertical line) to the end of curve. Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Computing areas under a density estimation curve is not a difficult job. Here is a reproducible example.

Suppose we have some observed data `x` that are, for simplicity, normally distributed:

```
set.seed(0)
x <- rnorm(1000)
```

We perform a density estimation (with some customization, see `?density`):

```
d <- density.default(x, n = 512, cut = 3)
str(d)
#    List of 7
# $ x        : num [1:512] -3.91 -3.9 -3.88 -3.87 -3.85 ...
# $ y        : num [1:512] 2.23e-05 2.74e-05 3.35e-05 4.07e-05 4.93e-05 ...
# ... truncated ...
```

We want to compute the area under the curve to the right of `x = 1`:

```
plot(d); abline(v = 1, col = 2)
```

[image]

Mathematically this is an numerical integration of the estimated density curve on `[1, Inf]`.

The estimated density curve is stored in discrete format in `d$x` and `d$y`:

```
xx <- d$x  ## 512 evenly spaced points on [min(x) - 3 * d$bw, max(x) + 3 * d$bw]
dx <- xx[2L] - xx[1L]  ## spacing / bin size
yy <- d$y  ## 512 density values for `xx`
```

There are two methods for the numerical integration.

**method 1: [Riemann Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum)**

The area under the estimated density curve is:

```
C <- sum(yy) * dx  ## sum(yy * dx)
# [1] 1.000976
```

Since *Riemann Sum* is only an approximation, this deviates from 1 (total probability) a little bit. We call this `C` value a "normalizing constant".

Numerical integration on `[1, Inf]` can be approximated by

```
p.unscaled <- sum(yy[xx >= 1]) * dx
# [1] 0.1691366
```

which should be further scaled it by `C` for a proper probability estimation:

```
p.scaled <- p.unscaled / C
# [1] 0.1689718
```

Since the true density of our simulated `x` is know, we can compare this estimate with the true value:

```
pnorm(x0, lower.tail = FALSE)
# [1] 0.1586553
```

which is fairly close.

**method 2: [trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule)**

We do a linear interpolation of `(xx, yy)` and apply numerical integration on this linear interpolant.

```
f <- approxfun(xx, yy)
C <- integrate(f, min(xx), max(xx))$value
p.unscaled <- integrate(f, 1, max(xx))$value
p.scaled <- p.unscaled / C
#[1] 0.1687369
```

---

**Regarding [Robin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52415208/4891738)**

The answer is legitimate but probably cheating. OP's question starts with a density estimation but the answer bypasses it altogether. If this is allowed, why not simply do the following?

```
set.seed(0)
x <- rnorm(1000)
mean(x > 1)
#[1] 0.163
```

Comment: I see your point in the response to my answer and I think we read the question differently. Since the OP used density() to get the density estimate, they would have the original data. I don't think my answer is cheating when that's the case. They can indeed bypass integrating over the density estimate curve. I'm still learning so please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @李哲源 how to do when we must calculate the square of phi ? I mean how to calculate the same integrale but for square phi

Answer (score 5):

The Empirical Cumulative Distribution Function `ecdf()` in base R makes it very easy.  Using 李哲源's example...

```
#Reproducible sample data 
set.seed(0)
x <- rnorm(1000)

#Create empirical cumulative distribution function from sample data
d_fun <- ecdf (x)

#Assume a value for the "red vertical line"
x0 <- 1

#Area under curve less than, equal to x0
d_fun(x0) 
# [1] 0.837

#Area under curve greater than x0
1 - d_fun(x0)
# [1] 0.163
```

**Regarding 李哲源's response to my answer.** Their answer assumes you only have the density estimate curve. My answer assumes you have the original data, which is applicable to the the OP's question since they used `density()` to get the density estimate curve.